# docker-machine - connection refused error

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, portforwarding, docker-machine

I'm using docker-machine, docker-compose on mac OS to start up my container.

In my docker-compose.yml, i have

```
ports:
    - "8080:8080"
expose:
    - "3000"
    - "8000"
    - "8080"
```

Steps to create docker-machine

- docker-machine create testdocker --driver=virtualbox
- eval "$(docker-machine env testdocker)"
- docker-compose up -d (all containers start up properly)

  - docker-machine ip localdocker
    192.168.99.101
  - open http://192.168.99.101:8080
  - echo ${DOCKER_HOST_IP}
    192.168.99.101
  - open http://${DOCKER_HOST_IP}:8080 (// doesn't open - times         out/connection refused)
  - curl http://192.168.99.101:8080
    Connection refused

I logged into the docker container and on 'telnet localhost 8080', i get connection refused error again. What am i doing wrong? I'm stumped.

Answer (score -1):

Try just ping without port number. You can't ping with port number. Check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port) answer.